# Twilio gets a 502 Bad Gateway for a URL that responds properly to me

Tags: twilio

**This problem was an internal networking issue on our side. It was not an issue with Twilio or their API**

When my app contacts Twilio it passes a call back URL so Twilio can get additional info.  I never see the request from Twilio but I get a call telling me that an application error has occurred.

When I check the Twilio debugging log it says it got a "502 Bad Gateway" error for the URL I passed it. However, when I try the same URL, I get a response just fine.

My app is running on a non-standard port but I'm pretty sure Twilio doesn't care about that.

What can cause Twilio to get a 502 when I don't

Here's the response I get when I hit the URL

```
<Response>
<Gather action="http://dev1.onshift.com/twilio/user_response_handler?sendID=38297795" method="POST" numDigits="1">
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/wavs/254_preamble.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/wavs/8144924.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/static/messages/handle_human_footer.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/wavs/254_preamble.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/wavs/8144924.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/static/messages/handle_voicemail_footer_v2.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/wavs/8144924.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/static/messages/handle_voicemail_footer_v2.wav</Play>
    <Play>http://dev1.onshift.com/static/messages/goodbye.wav</Play>
</Gather>
</Response>
```

Comment: Hey, Twilio employee here. Could you give us a bit more information on what you see when you try to access the URL that you're getting the TwiML response back from? (On your own web server).

Comment: I added to the question because the response was too long. I suspect your request is not even getting to my server. I've yet too see it in the access logs.

Comment: BTW, here's the URL (direct from your app monitor): http://dev1.onshift.com:9292/twilio/send_message/38297801

Comment: Is that link behind some firewall or gateway? When I try to send a cURL to it, it just hangs, eventually timing out.

Comment: You know what, it wasn't in the past but I think there's been some network changes here. Perhaps I can only access it because I'm in the building.

Yeah, it down't look like I can access it either from outside.

Comment: I am having similar issue. My Network people are saying that it is set up correctly and in the past all was working fine. But suddenly now we are getting the 502 bad gateway error for new set up. For old set up that was working earlier is throwing 404 error. Not sure what's going on with Twilio.

Comment: In my case there was a change on our network that blocked the server I was working on from outside of our network. Your network people may be wrong or confused. If you know the URL you're passing to Twilio you can prove them right or wrong by seeing if you can hit that URL from outside your network.

You can try from home, or, what I did was turn off wireless on my phone and tried to hit the URL from it. I couldn't do it although it worked from my laptop on the company wifi.

If you can't hit the URL from outside your network neither can Twilio

Comment: In my case I was posting to a https url that didn't support SSL over the www domain. I had to remove the 'www.' and POS to the naked domain.

Comment: Hey dl__, would you mind putting your response in the answer section?

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comments above:

> In my case there was a change on our network that blocked the server I
>   was working on from outside of our network. Your network people may be
>   wrong or confused. If you know the URL you're passing to Twilio you
>   can prove them right or wrong by seeing if you can hit that URL from
>   outside your network. You can try from home, or, what I did was turn
>   off wireless on my phone and tried to hit the URL from it. I couldn't
>   do it although it worked from my laptop on the company wifi. If you
>   can't hit the URL from outside your network neither can Twilio

Follow these [suggested steps](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200) will help others begin to debug as they receive this error.